# configure nginx for multiple laravel projects

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have 2 laravel projects, one in /var/www/markman and the other in /var/www/larapp, I managed to get them to work one at a time (on "/"), but not together (let's say, one on "/" and the other on "/markman"). I installed phpmyadmin and managed to get it to work just fine on /phpmyadmin.
the content of the nginx config:

```
 server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/larapp/public;        
        server_name 140.82.55.247;

        location / {                
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location /markman {                
                root /var/www/markman/public;
                rewrite ^/markman/(.*)$ /var/www/markman/public/index.php?$1 last;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }


        location /phpmyadmin {
            root /usr/share/;
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                }
        }

}
```

any recommendations are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Homestead: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead

It comes with nginx, php7 and mysql.

I used it to manage all my projects in one place. It's really easy to set up (I set it up on my MacBook) as it uses a virtual environment with something like VirtualBox https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

My `Homestead.yaml` config file looks like this

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 4096
cpus: 4
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Development
      to: /var/www

sites:
    - map: project-one.local
      to: /var/www/Project-One/public
    - map: project-two.local 
      to: /var/www/Project-Two/public

databases:
    - project_one_db
    - project_two_db
```